# Visual C++ Куча была повреждена (параметры: 0x774BCDD8)

Tags: c++, массивы, visual-c++, исключения, шаблоны-с++

Здравствуйте! Пишу свой класс Array, который представляет из себя массив. 
При вызове метода append() программа выдаёт исключение

> Куча была повреждена (параметры: 0x774BCDD8)

/

> Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x0025FDCC.

Код класса `Array`:

```
enum Mode {
    Immutable = 0x01,
    Mutable = 0x02
};
Array(Mode _Mode = Array::Mode::Mutable, size_t _Size = 0) {
    max_size = _Size;
    mode = _Mode;

    _size = 0;
    arr = new T[max_size];

    for (size_t i(0); i < max_size; i++)
        arr[i] = NULL;
}
bool append(const T value) {
    if (mode == Mode::Mutable)
    {
        if (_size == max_size)
            max_size++;
        arr[_size] = value;
        _size++;
        return true;
    }
    else if (mode == Mode::Immutable && _size < max_size)
    {
        arr[_size] = value;
        _size++;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "Memory is full!" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Код функции `main`:

```
int main()
{   
    Array<int> arr;

    for (int i(0); i < 15; i++)
        arr.append(i);

    for (int i(0); i < 15; i++)
        std::cout << arr[i] << std::endl;

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по приведенному коду, при вызове конструктора по умолчанию вы выделяете память для нулевого размера, т.е. по сути не выделяете ее. При этом устанавливая флаг `Mutable`. Далее при добавлении вы выполняете запись в память, которая так и не выделена:

```
    arr[_size] = value;
```

Что ж удивляться, что программа не работает?

Я бы на вашем месте делал примерно так (написано на коленке, не компилировал - для показа идеи):

```
Array(Mode _Mode = Array::Mode::Mutable, size_t _Size = 0)
{
    max_size = _Size;
    if (max_size < 1) max_size = 1;
    mode = _Mode;
    _size = 0;
    arr = new T[max_size];
}

bool append(const T value)
{
    if (mode == Mode::Mutable)
    {
        if (_size == max_size)
        {
            T* tmp = new T[max_size*=2];
            for(int i = 0; i < _size; ++i)
                tmp[i] = arr[i];
            delete[] arr;
            arr = tmp;
        }
        arr[_size] = value;
        _size++;
        return true;
    }
    ...
```

Comment: спасибо, помогло))